# Table > tr hover button height need some fix

Tags: html, css

Any proper HTML code will be helpful if you think my css is wrong.

I have attached screen shot.

**Problem :** Red box inside Green box. I am unable to reduce the height of RED box and to make green box fit inside each row.
tried alot but no success.

*Box should stay at the same position if i minimize or maximize browser. Working fine right now.*

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table id="main-table" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="small" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
                    <div>
                        <span >JavaScript Basics</span>
                        <button class="destroy"></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="small" colspan="1" rowspan="1">24</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-table {
position: relative;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}

#main-table tr td{

    padding: 3.6pt 0pt 3.6pt 3.6pt;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-width: 1pt;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-style: dashed;
    height: 20pt;
}

button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    appearance: none;
}

button,
input[type="checkbox"] {
    outline: none;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#main-table tr .destroy {
       background-color: green;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    /*height: 30px; */
    margin: auto 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #cc9a9a;
    margin-top: -40px;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#main-table tr .destroy:hover {
    color: #af5b5e;
}

#main-table tr .destroy:after {
    content: '×';
    background-color: red;
}

#main-table tr:hover .destroy {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little change in your **CSS** will help you to achieve what you're seeking.

For better look see [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/d3w5g5j2/1)

Changed **CSS** code:

```
#main-table tr td {
  padding: 3.6pt 0pt 3.6pt 3.6pt;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-width: 1pt;
  position: relative; /* Added */
  border-color: #999999;
  border-style: dashed;
  height: 20pt;
}
#main-table tr .destroy {
 background-color: green;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 10px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 100%;  /* Added */
 margin: auto 0;
 font-size: 35px;
 color: #cc9a9a;
 transition: color 0.2s ease-out;}

#main-table tr .destroy::after {  /* Added Most of the properties */
   content: '×';
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 65%;
   line-height: 33px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   right: 0;
}
```

Further for more changes all you have to do is, to play with your **CSS**.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/8sdtv3qj/
All I changed was

```
font-size: 25px;
top: 44px;
left: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `font-size` to `#main-table tr .destroy` same as `#main-table tr td` height. i.e. `height: 20pt;` (`font-size: 20pt;` for `#main-table tr .destroy`).
And remove `margin` and give `top:0` to it.

And give `position: relative;` to `#main-table tr td`

**[Updated working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjLokrsa/)**

Answer (score 0):

[What is css content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

see this example:

```
#main-table tr:hover .destroy {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px; // change added
    font-size: 24px; // change added
}
```

```css
#main-table {
position: relative;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}

#main-table tr td{

    padding: 3.6pt 0pt 3.6pt 3.6pt;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-width: 1pt;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-style: dashed;
    height: 20pt;
}

button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    appearance: none;
}

button,
input[type="checkbox"] {
    outline: none;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#main-table tr .destroy {
       background-color: green;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    /*height: 30px; */
    margin: auto 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #cc9a9a;
    margin-top: -40px;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#main-table tr .destroy:hover {
    color: #af5b5e;
}


#main-table tr .destroy:after {
    content: '×';
    background-color: red;
}

/* changed */
#main-table tr:hover .destroy {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table id="main-table" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="small" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="1">
                    <div>
                        <span >JavaScript Basics</span>
                        <button class="destroy"></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="small" colspan="1" rowspan="1">24</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```